# How to call event on the select only when condition meets in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a method that opens the modal.

I need to open modal only when select component option value is "I have a coupon"

```
 <Select
          placeholder="Want to get a discount"
          @click="openModal"
          v-model="coupon.source"
        >
      ...
```

How can I conditionally fire that openModal() method only when value is v-model is "From Groupon" selected otherwise don't call any method at all?

Comment: Hi, Can you share the code for `openModal` method, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you using a specific library? You could make a `@change` and handle the state there (`coupon.source`) rather than relying on `v-model` which will lack flexibility, as in your case.

Comment: @kissu what do you mean?

Comment: Can you please give us some more context, code, a [repro] or a github repo. That way, we will be able to help you. What I meant by the `@change`, is watching the `$event` and reacting accordingly. As explained in this first paragraph: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage >> `select fields use value as a prop and change as an event`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "From Groupon" condition in the on click function,openModal and decide what action need to be taken